# How can I cluster a continuous percentage?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I've got a table with 3 columns. 
1 is descriptive A
1 is a percentage B
1 is a decimal number C

I would like to investigate for the clusters (ie. B is high ad C is low, or viceversa). 
How can I start this task?

I'm not very experienced with this task in Mathematica. I've used Excel to plot it but I think is really not satisfying.

[image]

The document with the data set
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/143HGBAxygavCjs1fiHPIgB3l1S7zUPbCw_5W9_2SPjk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You could start by showing what you've tried, and providing some example data and example results you're after (the latter c/b fabricated, just to show readers what you want).

Comment: I've added an image and some analysis. But I'm not very used to cluster analysis with mathematica. I've never used it for this purpose before.. You can see the clusters very clearly in the graph..

Comment: Off-topic because not enough information is given to proceed in a useful way, plus the question seems to be more about how to do something productive with the data in general, than how to do it in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: mmm.. your point is pretty interesting. The creator of this community (StackExchange) said that the environment leads and change the people which are living in it. When you split the environment (Mathematica) from the solution of Data Analysis provided, you are making a non trivial ipothesi. The opinion you just expressed (*the question seems to be more about how to do something productive with the data in general, than how to do it in Mathematica*) is more an intuition or an exhaustive analysis that you would sign with your name, as a professionist?

Comment: It is stated as a personal opinion that other people may agree or disagee with at their option. StackExchange sites are community-driven and based on a voting system for most decisions; judging by the votes, at least four other people agreed with me. Simply put, your question is not of the standard we are accustomed to receiving on this site, and if you want to have it re-opened, you should take care to clarify it. To turn your objection around, would you be willing to sign this poor effort with your real name, I wonder? Also, please note that it was not me who downvoted you.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.: a few days ago I replied to a guy on Facebook (so with my name). He was speaking of "the lack of effort" and I took the defense of the blamed guy. The guy waited 2 hours before answering only then he replied. But that day I put really a lot on effort at explaining how easily we speak of lack of effort pretending of being rational and right. Here, I will just say: you see my question as something to be ashamed of. And this is a very good point about your psychology. If you really want to do an effort, spend some time reading this: http://goo.gl/TWq2Y2

Comment: You seem willing to spend more effort trying to imply some psychological defect on my part, than bringing your question up to community standards, or even solving your actual problem. I have to say, this bizarre response to even the mildest criticism speaks for itself.

Comment: @OleksandrR.: Once I got a question with 28 downvotes and the question was perfectly in the standard, of course the high-rep users simply advised me to improve the quality. I did and nothing changed. I took it as a play. This community is not perfect, humans are not, but the ability of admitting when something is not working is something that I really appreciate in men. Here, often, it lacks completely. The effort for solving the problem by myself is very high and I think the answer I got is very more productive of your intervention. You simply lacked of effort, not less than me.

Comment: If you really think this: "not enough information is given to proceed in a useful way" and want to show effort you should provide an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data provided is missing the descriptor, which could be also used for data analysis.
Using the data provided above.

```
data = {{19, 5.5`}, {20, 30}, {25, 3.9`}, {38, 4}, {43, 30}, {10, 
    88}, {12, 6.4`}, {67, 13}, {67, 23}, {100, 10}, {3, 9.9`}, {3, 
    5.9`}, {12, 21}, {12, 5.1`}, {17, 20}, {20, 24}, {25, 16}, {33, 
    24}, {33, 40}, {50, 5}, {50, 3.5`}, {50, 8}, {100, 10}, {100, 
    22}, {100, 35}, {100, 1}, {100, 18}, {100, 10}, {100, 32}, {100, 
    44}, {100, 1}, {100, 23}, {100, 55}, {100, 5}, {0, 40}, {0, 
    19}, {0, 8.6`}, {0, 31}, {0, 5.9`}, {0, 41}, {0, 8.8`}, {0, 
    33}, {0, 39}, {0, 11}, {0, 10}, {0, 67}, {0, 3.3`}, {0, 38}, {0, 
    150}, {0, 23}, {0, 260}, {0, 7.9`}, {0, 70}, {0, 230}, {0, 
    7.1`}, {0, 120}, {0, 260}, {0, 30}, {0, 7.1`}, {0, 23}, {0, 
    7.5`}, {0, 20}, {0, 10}, {0, 27}, {0, 24}, {0, 1}, {0, 8.6`}, {0, 
    22}, {0, 32}, {0, 4.2`}, {0, 28}, {0, 32}, {0, 5.3`}, {0, 29}, {0,
     37}, {0, 38}, {0, 11}, {0, 6}, {0, 21}, {0, 13}, {0, 1.8`}, {0, 
    140}, {0, 19}, {0, 7.2`}, {0, 25}, {0, 7}, {0, 8}, {0, 37}, {0, 
    5.5`}, {0, 20}, {0, 88}, {0, 38}, {0, 45}, {0, 10}, {0, 29}, {0, 
    34}, {0, 44}, {0, 9.7`}, {0, 8.3`}, {0, 20}, {0, 38}, {0, 35}, {0,
     190}, {0, 7}, {0, 9}, {0, 41}, {0, 5.3`}, {0, 29}, {0, 10}, {0, 
    41}, {0, 11}, {0, 20}, {0, 26}, {0, 4}, {0, 28}, {0, 5}, {0, 
    5.5`}, {0, 47}, {0, 11}, {0, 17}, {0, 5}, {0, 30}, {0, 20}, {0, 
    210}, {0, 2.5`}, {0, 10}, {0, 44}, {0, 25}, {0, 30}, {0, 34}, {0, 
    31}, {0, 4}, {0, 57}, {0, 45}, {0, 21}, {0, 42}, {0, 170}, {0, 
    10}, {0, 43}, {0, 18}, {0, 2}, {0, 6}, {0, 4}, {0, 7.5`}, {0, 
    21}, {0, 95}, {0, 8.5`}, {0, 26}, {0, 94}, {0, 4}, {0, 8}, {0, 
    90}, {0, 9}, {0, 44}, {0, 110}, {0, 3}, {0, 49}, {0, 17}, {0, 
    87}, {0, 62}, {0, 37}, {0, 27}, {0, 29}, {0, 160}, {0, 30}, {0, 
    98}, {0, 6}, {0, 20}, {0, 4}, {0, 35}, {0, 33}, {0, 230}, {0, 
    3}, {0, 21}, {0, 4}, {0, 10}, {0, 16}, {0, 7}, {0, 49}, {0, 
    450}, {0, 4}, {0, 27}, {0, 4}, {0, 44}, {0, 20}, {0, 15}, {0, 
    160}, {0, 20}, {0, 36}, {0, 5}, {0, 10}, {0, 1}, {0, 10}, {0, 
    20}, {0, 21}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}, {0, 80}, {0, 27}, {0, 37}, {0, 
    19}, {0, 130}, {0, 12}, {0, 4}, {0, 72}, {0, 10}, {0, 35}, {0, 
    34}, {0, 48}, {0, 49}, {0, 24}, {0, 46}, {0, 27}, {0, 6}, {0, 
    30}, {0, 43}, {0, 8}, {0, 59}, {0, 120}, {0, 31}, {0, 23}, {0, 
    16}, {0, 96}, {0, 23}, {0, 49}, {0, 69}, {0, 38}, {0, 25}, {0, 
    44}, {0, 41}, {0, 28}, {0, 110}, {0, 6}, {0, 8}, {0, 3}, {0, 
    42}, {0, 14}, {0, 330}, {0, 120}, {0, 63}, {0, 21}, {0, 21}, {0, 
    9}, {0, 8}, {0, 74}, {0, 42}, {0, 6}, {0, 12}, {0, 7}, {0, 
    48}, {0, 12}, {0, 83}, {0, 210}, {0, 34}, {0, 350}, {0, 32}, {0, 
    5}, {0, 18}, {0, 6}, {0, 82}, {0, 27}, {0, 190}, {0, 400}, {0, 
    29}, {0, 19}, {0, 100}, {0, 5}, {0, 10}, {0, 13}, {0, 40}, {0, 
    33}, {0, 15}, {0, 39}, {0, 6}, {0, 7}, {0, 7}, {0, 140}, {0, 
    64}, {0, 450}, {0, 48}, {0, 63}, {0, 53}, {0, 45}, {0, 49}, {0, 
    10}, {0, 10}, {0, 36}, {0, 43}, {0, 14}, {0, 21}, {0, 3}, {0, 
    38}, {0, 230}, {0, 160}, {0, 23}, {0, 250}, {0, 44}, {0, 24}, {0, 
    42}, {0, 13}, {0, 81}, {0, 5}, {0, 46}, {0, 18}, {0, 32}, {0, 
    110}, {0, 49}, {0, 3}};
Histogram3D[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Are you also familiar with the function: FindClusters? I would like to keep the description while making clusters. I am going to edit the question and add it.